# Open Source Tools for Swept-Path Analysis?

Tags: routing

Before I spend time writing something, does anybody know of any open source tools to perform swept-path analysis (preferably suitable to run on Windows and a Python API would be a bonus)?  I pretty sure I can figure it out, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: Do you mean as at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swept_path_analysis#Licensing ?

Comment: Yes.  I know there is a free plugin called turn.lsp but that doesn't really count as FOSS because you need AutoCAD.

Comment: I'll take the tumble-weed and silence as a "no, there is no FOSS swept-path analysis software".  Therefore, I have developed my own. I got a bit tricky because I had to account for rear-wheel steering, but I'm good to go.

Comment: Did you ever get round to developing a toll of some sort? I'm after something similar to run in QGIS.

Comment: I did develop such a tool, yes and use it commercially so I'm reluctant to release it.  I also wrote it using the key-frame spline deformation capabilities of a 3D modelling package to save a ton of coding on my part, so it wouldn't work in QGIS anyway.  Maybe something similar could be done using the CAD tools or curves in PostGIS?  If you do find a free tool of this nature - do report back because other will want to know.

Answer (score -3):

maybe this site is useful [www.sweptpath.com](http://www.sweptpath.com), perhaps you can use that turning template image.